# Can I find out if "redistributables" are already installed formally?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

A program uses a local-install approach and not a .msi installer and can't use an MSI module.  If the win10 *ucrt* has been installed or is native, I don't want to add my own local copy.  Likewise for the VS Redistributables: if the use has *formally* installed that previously or did so as a prior step, I want to know that, so if it has not been done, I can supply "local" versions.

The obvious idea is to try `LoadLibraryEx` with the default system search path. But I wonder if there is a call to ask if that's been installed properly, rather than possibly find a stray copy that happens to be on the path or whatnot.